# Error: is.integer(group) is not TRUE while using ggmap in R

Tags: r, ggmap

I am trying to plot some GPS locations on a map. I used "ggmap" library for this. While using ggmap command, I get below error-

*ggmap(mp)*

*Error: is.integer(group) is not TRUE*

Here is code snippet:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

mapgilbert = get_map(location = (Long=mean(as.numeric(datn$Long)),Lat=mean(as.numeric(datn$Lat))), zoom = 4,maptype = "satellite", scale = 2)

ggmap(mapgilbert)
```

Note : "datn" is data frame containing GPS locations in columns Lat and Long.

I tried using locations like "paris","texas" etc as given in R help (

```
map <- get_map(location = "texas", zoom = 6, source = "stamen")

ggmap(map, fullpage = TRUE))
```

but it didn't help. Still getting same error after ggmap command.

Comment: I upgraded ggplot2,ggmap and plyr. It solved the problem

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded ggplot2,ggmap and plyr. It solved the problem