# View/ save R plot on the Linux server

Tags: r, linux, plot, server

I am working on a remote Linux server with R. I have made a plot in R using ggplot().

```
p <- ggplot(new_df) + geom_line(aes(x=dt, y=user_cnt))
```

However, when I want to view the plot as

```
>p
```

I get the following error:
Error: is.integer(group) is not TRUE

Also when I want to save the plot to a file with the following code:

```
jpeg("myplot.jpg")
ggplot(new_df) + geom_line(aes(x=dt, y=user_cnt)
dev.off()
```

I still get the error: Error: is.integer(group) is not TRUE

This problem does not occur when I'm working with the RGui on Windows.
How can I view/save my plot on the Linux server? I am connected from Windows 10 using PuTTy.

Comment: A general comment, the preferred way to save a `ggplot` object is using `ggsave()`. :-)

Comment: ggsave() also gives the same error.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40762729/error-is-integergroup-is-not-true-while-using-ggmap-in-r)? Also, please post [enough information for us to debug this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: This error seems to be associated with posts on other forums that are several years old, suggesting that upgrading `ggplot2` and associated packages may help.

Comment: Upgrading the packages does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't view any pictures on TTY. So you need ftp tools.

To download Git, and install it. Then, open **Git Bash**, and use `sftp user@ip` to connect to your servicer. Finally use `get filesName` to get your files.

P.S. Excuse me for my poor English, please.

Answer (score 0):

Just to visualize you can use plot().

I.e. plot(p)

However I am also having issues with saving the plot (will update this if I figure out a solution).